# KivyMd screen does not change

Tags: python, kivy-language

I have this python file

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior, ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList



class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        icons_item = {
            'bug': 'Files'
        }

        for icon_name in icons_item.keys():
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget(
                ItemDrawer(icon=icon_name, text=icons_item[icon_name])
            )

class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):

    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        # Set the color of the icon and text for the menu item.
        for item in self.children:
            if item.text_color == self.theme_cls.primary_color:
                item.text_color = self.theme_cls.text_color
                break
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color

MainApp().run()
```

And this .kv file
See Line 3, the error, comes there that screen_manager is not defined

```
<ItemDrawer>:
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    on_release: screen_manager.current = 'screen2'

    IconLeftWidget:
        id: icon
        icon: root.icon
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 0,0,0,1

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "250", "250"
            source: "logo.jpg"

    ScrollView:

        DrawerList:
            id: md_list

NavigationLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        Screen:
            name: 'screen1'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'


                Widget:
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0,1,0.2117647058823529,0.3
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    id: content_drawer
        Screen:
            name: 'screen2'
```

When I click on the item in the navigation drawer, it says that **screen_manager is not defined**

What am I doing wrong? I searched the internet a lot but couldnot find anything useful

Help me please, how do i change screens?

Comment: Can you check the code you posted? When I test it, I'm only seeing a solid green box, so I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @bitinerant yup then on the screen, swipe from left to right

Comment: In my test, swiping on the empty green window does nothing. Also, you said, "when I click on the item in the navigation drawer" but there is no navigation drawer visible. I'm willing to help if you can make it easy for me to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @bitinerant what version of kivyMd are you using?

Comment: `__version__ = "0.104.0"`

Comment: Me as well, don't know why it is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

The MDNavigation Drawer should be at the same indent level as the ScreenManager. Furthermore,

```
        MDNavigationLayout:
            screen_manager:screen_manager
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: 'screen1'
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        MDToolbar:
                            title: "Navigation Drawer"
                            elevation: 10
                            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x:nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
    
                        Widget:
    
                Screen:
                    name: 'screen2'
                    
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    id: content_drawer
```

add the

```
screen_manager:screen_manager
```

beneath the NavigationLayout so that it can be **accessed** as an **ObjectProperty**. Finally change the ItemDrawer callback from

```
on_release: screen_manager.current = 'screen2'
```

to

```
on_release: app.root.screen_manager.current = 'screen2'
```

Finally you can also add

```
nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

**beneath your root window** and just **ontop/below** the line `screen_manager: screen_manager`
This enables for **dismissing** of the **navigation drawer** when the **new screen pops up**.

then update your callback to this:

```
on_release:
    app.root.screen_manager.current = 'screen2'
    app.root.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
```